# POWER BI - How to get MEDIAN of a WHOLE column that is a calculated Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm not sure how to approach this.

I need another measure to get the MEDIAN of the WHOLE COLUMN based on a calculated measure (Cty3|Cty4).

PHASE 1 - Cty3|Cty4 Divide by MEDIAN=
IFERROR(DIVIDE(MEDIAN(demo[Country3]),MEDIAN(demo[Country4])),BLANK())

MEDIAN the whole column of  is = Cty3|Cty4 1.00200(ACCORDING TO EXCEL MEDIAN()

I would like to have the median to showcase in "**Result** needed MEDIAN" so that I can create conditional formatting against that median

Please let me know if you can't access this link.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1321fxPGTEbQNzODsdxPRUowgbOJFQQ5T/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: It will be better to get `median` from a column rather than `measure`, because `measure` represent single value and will only split when display in `table`. To solve it, you have to create a new `table` for all the value you show above and get the `mean` from there

Comment: Try with variable. In your measure add clause 

var __Country3 = [Country3] --
var __Country4 - [Country4]
return
DIVIDE(MEDIAN(__Country3 ),MEDIAN(__Country4 ))